# Loading XML node inside ListBox and PivotControl (c# & Windows Phone 7)

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <root>
    <Sxoles>
        <sxoli>
            <onoma>name1</onoma>
            <sch>school1</sch>
            <sxoliId>100</sxoliId>
            <mathima>lesson1</mathima>
            <mathima>lesson2</mathima>


        </sxoli>
        <sxoli>
            <onoma>name2</onoma>
            <sch>school2</sch>
            <sxoliId>200</sxoliId>
            <mathima>lesson1</mathima>
            <mathima>lesson2</mathima>

        </sxoli>

    </Sxoles>
    </root>
```

I want to read **mathima** node and load inside a listbox (see bellow)

```
                           <Grid>
                                <ListBox x:Name="testList">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                                            x:Name="mathima"
                                            Style='{StaticResource                PhoneTextSubtleStyle}'
                                             />
                                      </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                            </Grid>
```

The list box is contained in a pivotitem of a pivotcontrol

As result i'd like to see lesson1, lesson2 etc... in the list (only the **mathima** node).

I created a class

```
 public class Sxoli
    {
        ...
        [XmlElement("mathima")]
        public string mathima { get; set; }

    }
```

In back code (.xaml.cs file) i have

```
mathima.Text = sxoli.mathima;
```

but i get the following error

"the name *mathima* does not exist in the current context"

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

You can get `mathima` values using `LINQ 2 XML`

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("yourXML.xml");//loads your xml
var mathimaList=doc.Descendants("Sxoles").Descendants("sxoli").Elements("mathima").Select(x=>x.Value);//gets mathima values
```

`mathimaList` now contains all the values of `mathima`..

Comment: Thnks for the answer! I'm completely newbie! So i use '  <TextBlock Text="{Binding mahtimaList}" 
                                           FontSize="25" />' to load the variable in my list. Is that correct?